# Queueable vs Schedulable vs Batch Apex?

Tags: asyncapexjob

Could somebody please clarify on which one to use under what conditions?

Apologies for asking question at a very broad level but I just want to know from people who handles large data, what is the approach you use?

Comment: Schedulables are often used to schedule batch apex to run at given intervals.  I don't have experience with the Queueable yet, but it seems like it might be a replacement for the combination of the two.

Comment: There is a similar chain. Have a look:
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56850/difference-between-database-executebatch-and-queueable-apex